# Use secp256k1 in Go

Tags: go, cryptography, certificate, bitcoin

I'm trying to use the elliptic curve *secp256k1* in Go with the library "crypto/x509". After the key pair generation, I obtain respectively the public key *pubKey* and the private key *privKey*. After that, I want to generate a certificate that include the public key, but before I want to store the private key in a *.pem* file:

```
keyDer, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(privKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to serialize ECDSA key: %s\n", err)
    }
```

but when I try to marshal an EC private key into ASN.1, DER format and to compile the code, I receive an error that said:

> Failed to serialize ECDSA key: x509: unknown elliptic curve

In this case it's necessary for me to work with that particular curve, so I cannot change to *prime256v1* or ''similar curve''. Is there a solution that permits to add the support for *secp256k1* in *crypto/x509* library, or another way/suggestion?

Comment: How are you generating the keys?

Comment: @VictorOliveira I'm working with the library: github.com/btcsuite/btcutil/hdkeychain. I'm generating the key as:
privKey, err := hdkeychain.NewMaster(seed, &chaincfg.MainNetParams)

//EC Private Key
sKey, err := privKey.ECPrivKey()

and finally as the question's code:
keyDer, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(privKey.ToECDSA())

Comment: why not just use the secp256k1 C library instead. You can still compile with cgo.

Comment: I used this https://github.com/sour-is/koblitz, then clone the Golang x509 package by starting from `x509.ParseCertificate()` and resolving all dependencies.

Noted: i'm not affiliated in anyway with the lib

Comment: @trung is there a public repository where your modified x509 package can be found?

Comment: @GaëtanLehmann I gave up the implementation as it's too complex with many invasive changes. Please do express your use cases in https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32874 so Go team can prioritize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is no secp256k1 curve type in go.](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#Curve)

How did you created key-pairs?

I faced this problem. In my case, I used the [go-ethereum](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1) package to create this curve type. So, I used the same package's [function](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto#FromECDSA) to parse the key.

So you have to use same package's specified function to parse the key-pair.

This x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(privKey) will only helps to Marshal go's standard curve type.

Comment: be aware that this go-ethereum implementation of `secp256k1` is not fully supported without cgo enabled https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.11.5/crypto/secp256k1/scalar_mult_nocgo.go#L13

Answer (score 3):

You can use secp256k1 module by [decred/dcrd](https://github.com/decred/dcrd/tree/master/dcrec/secp256k1). It is currently used by [btcsuite/btcd repo](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/074266215c26f8c4731330abb515f92b905f8dfa/go.mod).